# How to handle multiple response types in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Currently, I have a form, submitting which will redirect to an error page or download a file.
However, recently server side was modified, and as for now, it could also return some JSON, which I need to handle. Thus, as far as I've got, you can't get a form submission result, I've made a POST call instead of a form, but how could I handle different return types?
I ought to use jQuery for it, and currently it works as follows only for downloading:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'some-url',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                // some required data
            },
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function(response, status, req) {
                if (response.hasSuggestions) {
                    // this code is prepared to work with JSON data
                    return;
                }

                var fileName = req.getResponseHeader('content-disposition').split('; ')[1].replace('filename=', '');

                var contentType = req.getResponseHeader('content-type');

                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: contentType });

                var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                if (isIE) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                } else {
                    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
                    var a = $("<a />");
                    a.attr("download", fileName);
                    a.attr("href", link);
                    $("body").append(a);
                    a[0].click();
                    a.remove();
                }
            },
        error: // some error handler
    })
```

And if server returns JSON data or redirect, I'm just getting `"[object Blob]"`.
I know, that it is due to `response-type` field, but how could I handle different types of response?
P.S. If I'll not set a `response-type`, there will be a huge headache on properly converting string to blob

Comment: You can try do not set expected data type. Then when you receive data try to decode it as json and by success decide if you are working with json or blob.